# How to write a python script (on linux) that executes another script and exits?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want script a.py to execute script B.y, then exit immediately.
script B.y is then to continue running indefinitely and regularly as if run from the command line.
Target system is Linux Centos if it makes any difference

Comment: Did you read about [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Why not just run `python B.py &` from the command line?

Comment: Had it been possible to run B.py from the command line, or any other trivial solution, believe me, I would not have asked this question.  Nor could I have achieved that thus far with subprocess. An example would be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess [Popen subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is what you are looking for, i.e.:

For windows, something like:

```
import sys ,subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["C:/Python27/python.exe", "C:/path/to/script.py"])
sys.exit(0)
```

---

For linux, just change the path:

```
import sys ,subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/python", "/path/to/script.py"])
sys.exit(0)
```

Note:
To find python location on linux, you can use `which python`

Comment: I did just that except for used "python.exe" ass first param.  The "child" script ended when the parent ended. I want the "parent" script to end and the "child" script to continue running. I wonder if the difference - using full path in first param, is that important. But will try. Thanks

Comment: Works well on Windows, not on Linux.  In Linux the child process dies when the parent process finishes.